# How to import a segment of html into Excel

Tags: excel, aspose-cells

Requirement:

1.I need to export a table as a excel file.

2.I render it in a html page at first. I have a button to export to html.

My opinion:

1.I get the html from page:

```
document.getElementById('content').value = document.getElementById('containerId').innerHTML;

form1.submit();
```

2.I get it from server, response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel;" // it need the client has installed Microsoft Excel.

3.I got the right Excel file "XXXX.xls".

4.BUT BUT BUT, when I open it, it's alert a waring tell me like

```
  "it's not the right format of Excel, are you confirm to open it?"
```

I'm feel sorry to see it.

So I want to import the HTML section into a Excel file, then response the right Excel file to USER-AGENT.

**I have use the Aspose.Cells library in my project, I don't know how to use it to finish the task, Or is any other solution to solve it ?**

Answer (score 1):

If you need to parse html tags/portion to Excel spreadsheet using Aspose.Cells for .NET, you may use Cell.HtmlString attribute to set your desired html code segment in a cell, it will be parsed accordingly in the generated Excel file. Mind you, not all the html tags are supported at the moment.

Aspose.Cells for .NET also supports to convert an Excel file to Html file directly, see the documents on which file formats are supported for conversion, it may help you for your reference:
http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/opening-files.html
http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/saving-files.html

If you still have some issue/confusion, kindly give us details with your sample code using Aspose.Cells API, we can help you.